# Voltar página ao local exato com javascript

Tags: javascript

Olá,

Pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda com o history.back....

No caso é assim... eu clico em um artigo e depois nesse artigo tem uma seta de voltar que eu coloquei esse history.back, mas quando eu clico pra voltar, ele volta ao inicio da página e ao topo.

O que eu quero fazer é ele voltar no ponto onde eu tinha clicado.

Comment: O `history.back()`, por padrão, volta ao ponto de onde estava. É o mesmo que clicar na seta "Voltar" do navegador.

Comment: No meu caso ele está voltando ao topo sempre.

Comment: Então tem algo "especial" no seu site, porque isso não é o normal. Deve ter alguma coisa que faz ir pro topo, um script quem sabe. Quando vc faz scroll até a metade da página e aperta F5, ela atualiza no mesmo lugar ou vai pro topo também?

Comment: Também está voltando pro topo. Estou trabalhando com materialize e na página tem Tabs.

Comment: O Conteúdo do site está sendo puxando por um get em ajax.

Comment: Guarde o id da âncora que você clicou e ao invés do `history.back()` use um window.location.href para o mesmo lugar